# MaterializeCSS Setting Chips from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, materialize

I am stuck at this.
I have Multiple dates coming from database via ajax call, they are in the form of string, sperated by pipes like this,

```
var dates = $('#pm_date').val(responseData.site_detail["PM_Date"])
//  result > dates = "2016-03-01|2017-05-02|2016-06-13"
```

number of dates can vary and i dont have any control on that.

I want to display these dates as chips in materialize css.  i have split the dates into array, now i want to pass them to this function

```
$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
    }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
    }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
  });
```

if it was in php i could do like this

```
$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{

    <?php 

     for($i=0; $i<count($dates); $i++ ) {   
      echo "{ tag :" . $date[$i] .",},"; 
      }

   ?>
    }],
  });
```

How can I do this in java-script or JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you need for. I tried to do it with es2105 way with two examples and the last one is the old way. hope it helps.

```
// Option 1 (es2015 way)

let tags = [];
const dates = ["2016-03-01" , "2017-05-02", "2016-06-13"];

tags = dates.reduce((coll, item) => {
  coll.push({
    tag: item
  });
  return coll;
}, tags);


// Option 2 (es2015 way)

let tags2 = [];

for(d of dates) {
  tags2.push({tag: d});
}

// Option 3 (the old way)
var tags3 = [];
var dates3 = ["2016-03-01" , "2017-05-02", "2016-06-13"];

for(i=0; i < dates3.length; i++) {
  tags3.push({tag: dates3[i]});
}

// result 3

$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: tags3
});
```

Jsbin [Example code](https://jsbin.com/revopimiju/edit?js,console,output)